# IOS xpages date picker return "This field is not a valid date" when submitting a document

Tags: ios, date, ipad, xpages, picker

I am using a simple page with 1 text field.

```
Display type = Date/time
Display format = Date only
Date style = default
```

It works on a browser on the pc but on an iPad it returns "This field is not a valid date"
I notice that when picking a date on the iPad the format is different.
On a browser it is "Apr 21, 2017"
On the iPad "21 apr. 2017"

What am I doing wrong?

regards,
Peter

Comment: Seems to be only happening with domino server 9.0.1 FP8.  I created a PMR for it at IBM.. Keep you posted for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created a PMR for this and IBM came up with this workaround.
Why it happens since FP8 and not before is not mentioned.

On mobile there is a iOS picker, which allows you to select the date. An user cannot add an invalid date, so therefore client side validation is not technically required. You would allow the data to go to the server and check server validation there.
On web it is different, as in there is a date time picker and an edit box so user's can enter anything.
The client side validation is only checking that invalid data is not entered (not possible on mobile because of the native iOS/Android pickers
The server validation checks things like if it is expecting constraints such as date must be between last year & this year etc
So the suggested workaround is to can turn client side validation off for certain controls on mobile. And leave it one for web.
There is a snippet of code on the date time control which will check whether you are on mobile or web and set this to true or false based on that

```
<xp:this.disableClientSideValidation><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if(deviceBean.isMobile()){
return true;
}else if(deviceBean.isTablet()){
return true
}else{
return false;
}}]]></xp:this.disableClientSideValidation>
```

IBM Reports the fix wil be in release 9.0.1.FP9. IBM proposes another workaround. See below.You can create a custom theme in your app, with the following:

```
<theme extends="Bootstrap3_flat" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd" >
<control>
<name>InputField.DateTimePicker</name>
<property baseValue="com.ibm.xsp.DateTimeHelper">
<name>rendererType</name>
<value>com.ibm.xsp.theme.bootstrap.form.InputDateDetect</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>disableClientSideValidation</name>
<value>#{deviceBean.mobile || deviceBean.tablet}</value>
</property>
</control>
</theme>
```

Then in xsp.properties, choose the custom theme in the application theme dropdown Themes

help doc: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_theme.html

The effect of this is to disable client side validation for date time picker controls on mobile devices only.